# Inner join in 2 different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I use the below query to join 2 tables of different databases of same server.
Also let me know in which database I have to execute this query.

```
SELECT ...
FROM A.table t1
  JOIN B.table2 t2 ON t2.column = t1.col
```

Comment: Depends on the dbms product used. Tag the one you are using, and people can answer.

Comment: I am using SSMS 2008.. So in which database i have to execute the query..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we use join for two different database tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426929/can-we-use-join-for-two-different-database-tables)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to change that query a bit

```
Select * from Database1.[dbo].Table1 tab1
join Database2.[dbo].Table2 tab2 on tab1.ID = tab2.ID
```

or

```
Select * from Database1..Table1 tab1
join Database2..Table2 tab2 on tab1.ID = tab2.ID
```

Change names of databases, tables and IDs and give it a go

You can use it in all of connections on your server (every database), as your query have reference to databases

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responce Veljko89... But mail question is that in which DB i have to execute the query..

Comment: You can use it in all of connections on your server (every database), as your query have reference to both databases