# Assign primary key in one DB as foreign key in other DB

Tags: database, foreign-keys, primary-key, hsqldb

A Primary Key column in table A in database One...I want assign it as foreign key in table B in database Two...
both DB in same server, I'm using HSQLDB server 2.4 :

A- what would be the query?

B- I saw this way and I read it's not good practice,
   [Can we use join for two different database tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426929/can-we-use-join-for-)
         two-different-database-tables

is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with HSQLDB.

You can do this with two different schemas in the same database.

Comment: @fredit...Thanks..will go this way..though no complete separation between schemas(in term od integrity)