# Join Query from 2 Table in 2 Different Databases in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I have 2 databases needs to be joined.

Here is the query that I have but the `$db2` is only for the 2nd database, and `$this->db->query` only for 1st database.

```
     $akses = $db2->query("select A.uName, A.userPwd, A.[Nomor Induk], B.id_jabatan, B.nama FROM tUser A
                                LEFT JOIN karyawan B ON B.nik = A.[Nomor Induk]
                                LEFT JOIN bagian_departemen C ON C.id_bagian_dept = B.id_bagian_dept
                                WHERE A.uName = '$username' AND A.userPwd = '$password'"
                            );
```

I want to know the syntax to join 2 table from 2 databases.

Databases:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'helpdesk',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'striction' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$db['another_db'] = array(
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'produksi',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'striction' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we use join for two different database tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426929/can-we-use-join-for-two-different-database-tables)

Comment: is it capable syntax for codeigniter?

Comment: You tagged the question as SQL-Server, so if your Codeigniter is connected to a Microsoft SQL server, then yes it's valid, just use a raw query like in your first example. If you are using MySQL, then you need to change the tags in your question and that solution will not work for you

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$this->db->select("db1.table.column")
$this->db->join('db1.table', 'db1.table.column = db2.table.column');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: do we need to create connection to first and second database?

Comment: no, you don't need to define another connection. db1 is your actual database name and db2 is your another actual database name in mysql.

Comment: i tried this syntax

 $this->db->select("produksi.tUser.uName, produksi.tUser.userPwd, produksi.tUser[Nomor Induk], helpdesk.karyawan.id_jabatan, helpdesk.karyawan.nama");
  $this->db->join('helpdesk.karyawan', 'helpdesk.karyawan.nik = produksi.tUser.[Nomor Induk]');
  $this->db->join('bagian_departemen', 'helpdesk.bagian_departemen.id_bagian_dept = helpdesk.karyawan.id_bagian_dept');
  $query = $this->db->get();

but error 42000 is appear.

Comment: *[Nomor Induk]* why this, your query creating syntax error. print your last query and check where is syntax wrong.

Comment: [Nomor Induk] is the name of the column in table tUser

Comment: put this column between `\`Nomor Induk\`` and check. and its a bad idea to have space for table column name. you can use underscore.