# How to combine or store multiple results derived from a cursor into one resultset in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, cursor

The below one is the snapshot of the result sets derived from the cursor which I have used in my dynamic query where I am basically running the same script in multiple databases of a server by fetching databases names dynamically using a variable.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426929/can-we-use-join-for-two-different-database-tables#:~:text=SQL%20Server%20allows%20you%20to,same%20server%20%2D%20Db1%20and%20Db2%20.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/990750/tarik
This does not fulfil my requirement. I am getting the results in multiple result set which I want in one result set on real-time

Comment: Use union between the select statements.

Comment: _The below one_ What does that mean? Using a cursor will likely require that you store the result of each loop iteration in a temp table. But without code, that is just a guess.

Comment: Why not post what you actually have right now, and show us what you want to do with that data that it returns.