# Optimal way to find union of two data sets

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am working on a side project where I am comparing two different databases and want to find the common elements of the data sets based on the "id" field. I want to know if there is an optimal solution instead of using two nested for loops. Is there a way to do it with a hash map? Many Thanks!
Below is the sample code I am working with.

**UPDATE** all ids are unique with no possibility of there being a duplicate

```js
// data set 1
const set1 = [
  {
    id: "001",
    name: "bob",
    age: "50",
    location: "texas"
  },
    {
    id: "002",
    name: "bill",
    age: "51",
    location: "texas"
  },
    {
    id: "003",
    name: "ben",
    age: "52",
    location: "texas"
  },
    {
    id: "004",
    name: "cam",
    age: "53",
    location: "texas"
  },
    {
    id: "005",
    name: "max",
    age: "54",
    location: "texas"
  }
]

// data set 2
const set2 = [
  {
    id: "001",
    name: "bob"
  },
  {
    id: "002",
    name: "bill"
  }
]

// I want to create a function where I find the the common elements of the two lists based on id and put the common element of data set 1 into a list and return that list

const findUnion(set1, set2) {
  // logic here, I know I can do a nested for loop but is there a more efficient way such as 
  // using a hashmap? ( Map() object? ) 
}

// desired output 
const output = [
  {
    id: "001",
    name: "bob",
    age: "50",
    location: "texas"
  },
    {
    id: "002",
    name: "bill",
    age: "51",
    location: "texas"
  }
]
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426929/can-we-use-join-for-two-different-database-tables

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set`s for efficient lookup:

```
const ids1 = new Set(set1.map(({id}) => id));
const ids2 = new Set(set2.map(({id}) => id));
const output = set1.filter(({id}) => ids1.has(id) && ids2.has(id));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>First we combine into one long array. Then group by `id` using `reduce` method. Each group contains the item and count of appearances. Finally, for each of the groups, return only those with count of appearances > 1.</del>

Edit: fixed algorithm see code.

Edit 2: Made it more generic so order of items won't matter. This is by extending the duplicates rather then replacing them.

```js
function findUnion(set1, set2) {

  // first remove duplicates from each set
  // bonus: collect duplicates
  var duplicates;

  function dedup(set) {
    duplicates = []
    return Object.values(set.reduce(function(agg, item) {
      var merged = item;
      if (agg[item.id]) {
        merged = { ...agg[item.id],
          ...item
        }
        duplicates.push(merged)
      }
      agg[item.id] = merged;
      return agg
    }, {}));
  }

  set1 = dedup(set1);
  set2 = dedup(set2);

  // then combine
  var combined = [...set1, ...set2]

  // then remove duplicates again, this time keep them
  dedup(combined)
  return duplicates;
}

// data set 1
const set1 = [{
    id: "001",
    name: "bob",
    age: "50",
    location: "texas"
  },
  {
    id: "002",
    name: "bill",
    age: "51",
    location: "texas"
  },
  {
    id: "003",
    name: "ben",
    age: "52",
    location: "texas"
  },
  {
    id: "004",
    name: "cam",
    age: "53",
    location: "texas"
  },
  {
    id: "005",
    name: "max",
    age: "54",
    location: "texas"
  },
  {
    id: "005",
    name: "max",
    age: "54",
    location: "texas"
  },
  {
    id: "005",
    name: "max",
    age: "54",
    location: "texas"
  }
]

// data set 2
const set2 = [{
    id: "001",
    name: "bob"
  },
  {
    id: "002",
    name: "bill"
  }
]


// desired output 
const output = [{
    id: "001",
    name: "bob",
    age: "50",
    location: "texas"
  },
  {
    id: "002",
    name: "bill",
    age: "51",
    location: "texas"
  }
]

console.log(findUnion(set1, set2))
```

Comment: Yes I overlooked the possibility of duplicates in each list. Fix was to *remove* duplicates first. Then I refactored to re-use that code to *find* duplicates.

Comment: Note the difference between the requested output and yours.  Think it would be fixed if you set `combined` to `[...set2, ...set1]`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're looking for the *intersection*, not the *union*.

As others have said, we can use a `Set` to track uniqueness.  This gives us near `O(1)` lookup time, and allows us algorithm that runs in something like `O(m + n)` time where `m` and `n` are the sizes of your `set`s:

```js
const intersection = (s1, s2, ids = new Set (s2 .map (x => x .id))) =>
  s1 .filter (({id}) => ids .has (id))

const set1 = [{id: "001", name: "bob", age: "50", location: "texas"}, {id: "002", name: "bill", age: "51", location: "texas"}, {id: "003", name: "ben", age: "52", location: "texas"}, {id: "004", name: "cam", age: "53", location: "texas"}, {id: "005", name: "max", age: "54", location: "texas"}]
const set2 = [{id: "001", name: "bob"}, {id: "002", name: "bill"}]

console .log (intersection (set1, set2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```